# add a second div element to jquery script?

Tags: jquery

can someone please help me i am using a jquery splash screen which loads on page load, at the moment there is a div called splash screen that loads on startup but i want to add a div calle wrapper to this script below, so that both divs load up, how could i do that?

thanks

(function($){

```
    $.fn.splashScreen = function(settings){

        // Providing default options:

        settings = $.extend({
            textLayers      : [],
            textShowTime    : 1500,
            textTopOffset   : 80
        },settings);

        var promoIMG = this;

        // Creating the splashScreen div.
        // The rest of the styling is in splashscreen.css

        var splashScreen = $('<div>',{
            id  : 'splashScreen',
            css:{
                backgroundImage     : promoIMG.css('assets/img/drop.jpg'),
                backgroundPosition  : 'center '+promoIMG.offset().top+'px',
                height              : $(document).height()
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to append the spashscreen div to the body?

```
$("body").append(splashScreen);
```

Then do the same with your second div? append them both? Maybe I'm not understanding correctly.